# Creating an array of column vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, matrix

Basically i have a function that returns a column vector of size Z(100,1) of values. I want to run that function in a loop n times, and store each of those column vectors in a seperate index of an array, yet im having trouble doing this. This is my code that matlab does not like...

```
numSignals = 30;
Z = zeros(1,numSignals);

for n = 1:numSignals

    % load signal of to be reconstructed 
    Z(1,n) = loadSignal(n);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a matrix instead:

```
Z = zeros(100,numSignals);
for n=1:numSignals
    Z(:,n) = loadSignal(n);
end
```

Then you can call back the column vector you want with

```
Z(colIndex,:)
```

Matlab will not allow you to put anything other than a number into an entry of an array. If you really want the data structure you describe, then you will need to use a cell array instead. You can do this by

```
Z = cell(1,numSignals);
for n=1:numSignals
    Z{n} = loadSignal(n);
end
```

Comment: Im getting the following error when using the cells 
??? Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Error in ==> problem1 at 20
Z(n) = loadSignal(n);

Comment: nvm i needed to use {} to reference the index instead of (), thank you!